# Regex to capture values of key-value pairs

Tags: regex, key-value

I'm trying to capture the values of key-value pairs. For example in the following example, I'd want to capture the values "foo" and "bar".

Ex. node=foo type=bar

Comment: You can't capture multiple values in a single regexp. You need to use a loop to capture each key-value pair. The details of this depend on the programming language you're using.

Comment: So I realized that if I know the keys, it becomes easier. I'm actually trying to figure out a format for a log parser, so just using regex.

Comment: There are many log parsers already written.

Answer (score 1):

For a general understanding on capturing particular strings by a regex, you can regard the following pattern: **foo=bar**

```
(.*[^=])=(.*)
```

**foo** will be matched by the first group in parenthesis (match everything that is not an "=", means stop before the "=")

**=** will be matched by "=" directly

**bar** will be matched by the second group (everything else until line-end)

This works e.g. if your pairs are stored in a separate line per pair.
This just tries to explain, how capturing work in general.

For your particular example:  **node=foo type=bar**

```
.*[^=]=(.*[^ ]) .*[^=]=(.*[^ ])
```

The first parenthesis group will match **foo** and the second one **bar**

Be aware that the implementation for regular expression libraries may vary  and also be slightly different in various languages e.g. php, java, C++, etc.

There are several online-regex testers around to play with e.g.

https://regex101.com/

Comment: That will capture `node` and `foo`, not `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: he just wants to capture the values, not the keys.

Answer (score 0):

`^.+=(.*)` will capture `foo` and `bar` in your example.

I find [this](http://regexr.com/) website helpful for building / testing regex patterns